# JavaScript fill text input field and invoke autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I have some liquid code that generates a list of tag links and an autocomplete search box that loads results from a json file on every key press.
When the user clicks a tag, it is loaded into the text field but the search script is not invoked and the results from the search are not  loaded into the results container. How do I do this?

```
<ul class="tags">

{% for tag in page.tags %}

    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('MySearchBox').value='{{ tag }}';">{{ tag }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<!-- Html Elements for Search -->
<div id="search-container">
<input type="text" id="MySearchBox" name="MySearchBox" placeholder="search...">
<p><ul id="results-container"></ul></p>
</div>


<!-- Script pointing to search-script.js -->
<script src="/simple-jekyll-search.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<!-- Configuration -->
<script>
SimpleJekyllSearch({
  searchInput: document.getElementById('MySearchBox'),
  resultsContainer: document.getElementById('results-container'),
  json: '/search.json'
})
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: You have not provided what SimpleJekyllSearch is. For these types of questions, its suggested to provide a jsfiddle so that issue can be reproduced for other users.

Comment: Can you add a reproduceable code snipped to your post?

Comment: Here's the code https://jsfiddle.net/zddngwf6/2/